# Toast Array value not working

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I am trying to test to make sure my the value I want is in the array. Below the first toast works and just spits out my whole string of JSON data.

But the second toast which I am trying to show the value of [1] in my new JSONArray the jsonArray is giving me the following error  `jsonArray can not be defined to a variable` Am I not referencing it correctly?

```
try{
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonData);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, jsonData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, jsonArray[1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**EDIT**  based on the feedback it could also be a scope issue since it is in the "try" Do I have to use a try? and if so how do I make it available to the rest of the script.

Comment: There is a scoping issue. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSONArray` is just a Java object, not an array, which means you cannot use array indexing on it. Perhaps you meant `jsonData[1]`? Additionally, since `jsonArray` is declared and initialized in the `try` block, it is not in scope for the `Toast` call. Assuming that `jsonData` is a `Collection`:

```
try
{
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonData);
    // ...
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, jsonData.get(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
// ...
```

Comment: ok I thought the jsonArray is what turned it into a java array so I could use it in the rest of my project.

Comment: Nope, see how it's declared as a `JSONArray`? That means it's not a Java array. If you want to turn a `List` into an array, use [`List#toArray()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray()). I'm not sure why'd you'd want to do this, though - if you're just trying to index into a list, use [`List#get(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)).

Comment: Thanks I think I am using JSONArray for the incorrect reasons. Not sure why I need to put it into an array if I can read it directly like an array.

Comment: The [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) strikes again

Comment: Well played sir thanks for the link and I will make sure to use that as a guide when posting.

Answer (score 3):

Change the last line to:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, jsonArray.get(1).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Or, if you know that element 1 is a String,

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, jsonArray.getString(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**EDIT**

Based on your edit, I'm embarrassed that I didn't see it, but yes, you do have a scope issue. Move the Toasts inside the `try` block (in addition to what I suggested above).

Answer (score 2):

The jsonArray variable is not declared within the same scope as your Toast.

Try something like this:

```
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonData);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, jsonData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, jsonArray[1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```