# Using JSON data in the URLs found in my array

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I am trying to use the 2nd value of each of my JSON elemnts and use it in a array of web urls. What I am trying to end of with is a array of urls that include the image names from my json data below.

JSON Data:

```
[["1","Dragon Neck Tattoo","thm_polaroid.jpg","polaroid.jpg"],["2","Neck Tattoo","thm_default.jpg","default.jpg"],["3","Sweet Tattoo","thm_enhanced-buzz-9667-1270841394-4.jpg","enhanced-buzz-9667-1270841394-4.jpg"]]
```

MainActivity:

```
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
 String jsonData = bundle.getString("jsonData");


                try {

//THIS IS WHERE THE VALUES WILL GET ASSIGNED
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonData);


        private String[] mStrings=
            {
                 for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                    {
                       "http://www.mywebsite.com/images/" + jsonArray(i)(2),
                     }
             }


    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);



                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853659/toast-array-value-not-working/6853703#6853703), a `JSONArray` is just an [object](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html), not a [numerically-indexable array](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). It looks like you're having trouble with basic Java syntax, as well.

If you **actually** want to use a `String[]`, not a `List<String>`:

```
private String[] mStrings = new String[jsonArray.length()];

for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
{
    String url = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i).getString(2);
    mStrings[i] = "http://www.mywebsite.com/images/" + url;
}
```

If the `LazyAdapter` you're using can take a `List`, that'll be even easier to work with:

```
private List<String> mStrings = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
{
    String url = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i).getString(2);
    mStrings.add("http://www.mywebsite.com/images/" + url);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am still trying to wrap my head around the syntax among many other basic things. +1 Could you help me with an example using List<Sting> Or should I ask on another post.

Comment: Already edited my answer to include `List<String>`. BTW, try to be consistent and clean with your indentation - it will improve code readability significantly and make things easier in general.

Comment: Will do. Wish the tab key didn't focus on another window each time though.